# Aggregate polygons into specific shapes

Tags: vector, vector-grid, aggregation

So, I've basically got what amounts to a vector-based raster set.  It's a series of regular-sized squares that, for all intents and purposes, are raster pixels. The only reason it isn't a raster is because I need to store multiple attributes for each polygon.

I want to aggregate these polygons into larger, hexagonal tiles.  My plan right now is to just do a merge and use the "has center in" option to aggregate the centers of the rectangles into whatever hexagon their center exists in.

Are there other, more accurate ways to do this?  Such as splitting the rectangles along the hexagonal edges and averaging out the attribute values based on the percentage split?

Comment: If I were apportioning rectangles into a tessellated surface, I surely wouldn't be using hexagons, unless the rectangles were squares at the right scale to cut them into a pair of  triangles, then merge bunches of six triangles into hexagons.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? If ArcGis: Make Feature layer with ratio policy on attribute fields - intersect with hex grid - Dissolve